UI Vision French Language issue
I have a macro that adds a comment to a field in PeopleSoft. It works great for users who’s machine is set to English.
However for users, who’s machine is set to French Canada, any letters with “accents” gets replaced by a question mark in a diamond (refer to the screenshots below).
Any idea what causes this and how I can fix it?
The user’s can manually type the same words (wth accents) in the comment field and this behavior does not occur.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance to taking the time to look at this issue for me…
état de compte env à your business


Is your code actually doing the rendering of the text, or are you just providing text to the UI and it's doing the display? If the former, post your code that renders the text. If it's the latter, your question isn't about programming, and belongs on [su] instead.
